# c# .net core 2 web api: correct HTTP result for missing parent object and / or validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-webapi

Consider the following URL

This is a sample example, I'm using customers and order here, for an easy understanding of the setup.

In the order controller:

```
[HttpGet("~/api/customer/{customerId:int}/orders", Name = nameof(GetOrdersByCustomerIdAsync))]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(404)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<OrderListItemResourceModel>>> GetOrdersByCustomerIdAsync(int customerId:int){}
```

Question 1: Should this method actually exists in the CustomerController or the OrderController?
For me it made more sense in the Order controller as I do return orders here, but the routings is that of a customer, ...

Question 2: In my Core & Data layer, the Order object has a customer linked to it. The binding model in my api layer has an integer CustomerId
Where do I validate that the given customer id actually is from an existing customer? 
Is it ok to validate this in the controller by calling the customer service?
If so, can I just return NotFound()? Or should I do something else, so that it is clear to the user that it was the customer that is not found?

Again, this is a fictional example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1** - `~/api/customer/{customerId:int}/orders` in Customers controller or Orders controller?

**Customers Controller**

Here you are accessing orders as a property of a customer, therefore that action falls under customer controller. But if you were accessing, say `~api/orders` this would fall under Orders controller as this is accessing orders resources independent of any other resource.

**Question 2** - where to validate customer Id against existing db records

This is rather dependent on your implementation. Asp.Net Core provides functionality to do this from virtually anywhere - Filters, Services, etc - via dependency injection. So this depends on the structure of your application.

**Whether you can return `NotFound()` ?**

**Yes**.

If customerId does not match any existing customer, **NotFound** would be the appropriate response according to [the HttpStatusCode 404 Description](https://httpstatuses.com/404).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regarding question 2. I do use dependency injection. Service in controller. Repositories into service. I do not validate anything on the repository, that happens in the core. Repo is for storage only. I'm just wondering. With the notfound i can specifiy an object. Should I just add a string there to lets a customer was not found when getting the orders?

Comment: So service my be your best bet.You can specify any object with the `NotFound(/*any object, string, etc*/)` result. These  are passed as the response body to your client. However, you should understand that it comes with the issue of consistency across all actions that might return 404 (or any status code). In my experience, I use custom exceptions ( `throw new ResourceNotFoundException()`) in my controller actions, then use middleware to handle the exception in to a response, which will be consistent throughout my apis. But this is just my way, there could be a lot more better implementations.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I already have some basic error handling set up for the api. I like your idea of the ResourceNotFoundException. I was about to remove my exception handling from the services to the api. But this way I can keep them in the service, and still use the NotFound. Thanks again :) accepting your answer

Comment: 404 shouldn't be used for a successful call that just had no results to return

Comment: @p3tch yes when you are expecting an array, you return 200 with body as empty array, but when looking for a specific resource, e.g. by Id, and it doesnt exist, 404 is the appropriate response.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the title/second question

For an API, not something that will be accessed via a web browser, you should return something more useful than 404 Not Found. I strongly disagree with using 404 for an API call that was successful, but had no data.

`NoContent()` (status code 204) would be better suited as there was no fault with the route or the call itself, there's just no content for it to give back.

As per the RFC 2616 HTTP protocol definition, 400 responses are for

> Client Error - The request contains bad syntax or cannot
>       be fulfilled

There's no client error here, there's just no data for that ID. Whereas 200 responses...

> Success - The action was successfully received,
>       understood, and accepted

This fits your scenario much better than the 400 responses, because the server received, understood and accepted the request.